# Very slow file operation

Tags: files, io, disk

I recently rebuild a machine with Centos 5.8 with a brand new disk. 
This machine is old and has been running 5.8 for a long period with no issues so the only thing which changed recently is the new much larger disk.
However all the file operations are extremely slow since the machine was rebuilt with the new disk.

My knowledge about OS admin stuff is very limited and I will appreciate if someone can point me to where should I be looking at for finding the root cause. What commands or utilities I could use?

There is a java based back up program running on this machine which is constantly reading from the disk but the same program was running on this machine before the rebuild too and machine has been behaving fine for almost 2 years while this program ran at all times. But now the machine is not very usable and even the back up program is crawling.

This is the output of the iostat command:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.67    0.41    1.70   52.66    0.00   44.56

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda              24.87       197.21        53.98  238224706   65205070
sda1              0.00         0.00         0.00       2266         14
sda2             24.87       197.21        53.98  238222160   65205056
sdb              91.76       138.66       903.42  167496875 1091305280
sdb1             91.76       138.66       903.42  167496635 1091305280
dm-0            157.98       335.87       957.40  405716746 1156511560
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00       1376        216
```

And here is the snippet from the iotop command:

```
 8723 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 98.49 % [pdflush]
  588 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 75.71 % [kjournald]
    8 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  5.19 % [events/0]
13161 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  1.25 % java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dapp=CrashPla~ang:./skin com.backup42.desktop.CPDesktop
10668 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.63 % artsd -F 10 -S 4096 -s 60 -m artsmessage -l 3 -f
16681 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.09 % sshd: root [priv]
 3792 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.09 % python -E /usr/bin/sealert -s
13060 be/7 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.09 % java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dapp=CrashPla~hplan/lang com.backup42.service.CPService
13141 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dapp=CrashPla~ang:./skin com.backup42.desktop.CPDesktop
10672 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % artsmessage -i Sound server informational~l continue, using the null output device.
13049 be/7 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dapp=CrashPla~hplan/lang com.backup42.service.CPService
13162 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dapp=CrashPla~ang:./skin com.backup42.desktop.CPDeskto
```

Though I Don't know what to look for here..

#### UPDATE #1

Here is the output of iotop after killing crashplan. 
What is this 'rsync' process ? I am not running any rsync on the machine.
Looks like 'updatedb' and 'rsynch' are using up all the IO..

```
Total DISK READ: 124.78 K/s | Total DISK WRITE: 0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
20772 be/7 root       14.68 K/s    7.34 K/s  0.00 % 99.99 % updatedb -f sysfs
17446 be/4 root      110.10 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 92.75 % [rsync]
  155 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.09 % [kacpid]
20214 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 92.75 %  0.09 % bash /usr/bin/run-parts /etc/cron.daily
  264 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % [cqueue/0]
20767 be/7 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % sh /etc/cron.daily/mlocate.cron
20213 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % crond
```

Output of iostat:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.15    0.41    2.91   53.18    0.00   42.36

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda              25.00       197.88        86.24  254108937  110753694
sda1              0.00         0.00         0.00       2431         14
sda2             25.00       197.87        86.24  254104429  110753680
sdb              92.12       141.39      2951.64  181571178 3790455360
sdb1             92.12       141.39      2951.64  181570594 3790455360
dm-0            418.25       339.26      3037.88  435672794 3901209424
dm-1              0.00         0.00         0.00       1376        216
```

Comment: It looks like CrashPlan is running. Maybe when the machine was rebuilt, CrashPlan was set up as if this were a new machine, one on which the files had never been backed up before. Normally when you set up CrashPlan on a rebuilt system, you can choose an existing backup to use so that it won't have to copy over everything again.

Comment: No, that is not the case. I did the adaption as you mentioned. It is not just the crashplan, everything is extremely slow on the machine, making it unusable for any purpose.

Comment: OK. If you run the CrashPlan app, what does it say it's busy doing? If you pause CrashPlan and run iotop and iostat, what is running?

Comment: Ok, I killed crashplan and here is the output of iotop after that:

Comment: Total DISK READ: 124.78 K/s | Total DISK WRITE: 0.00 B/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                                                                         
20772 be/7 root       14.68 K/s    7.34 K/s  0.00 % 99.99 % updatedb -f sysfs
17446 be/4 root      110.10 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 92.75 % [rsync]
  155 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.09 % [kacpid]
20214 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s 92.75 %  0.09 % bash /usr/bin/run-parts /etc/cron.daily
  264 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %